# How could I have improved my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

I want to ask better questions. I had an issue regarding splash screens today and formatted this question:

[c# wpf splashscreen.Close is not working to close splashscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768058/c-sharp-wpf-splashscreen-close-is-not-working-to-close-splashscreen)

I am wondering as to what I could have done better?

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong. It got an answer didn't it?

Comment: Looks alright to me...

Comment: Do not put tags in the title. It creates noise. There is dedicated space for tags.

Comment: Enable the spell checker in the browser (it will catch simple spelling mistakes). The spell checker is more cumbersome to enable than necessary (at least in Firefox), but it is possible.

Comment: @Dharman Do not put answers in the comments. It creates noise. There is dedicated space for answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your question is relatively fine as is, but I think you could condense it a little. Currently it feels a bit over the place, and a bit long-winded. I'd love to be able to *suggest* an edit for your approval but that is not possible, so here I will write my suggestion. Note I am not a C# expert

> I have made a class, I make an instance of. In said instance I have these lines of code to show and close the splashscreen.
>
> code SNIPPET

I think you could avoid most of this, and just lead with your minimal but complete example you have at the bottom. e.g.

> I have the following class which manages a `SplashScreen`:

```
entire minimal example at the bottom of your question
```

You then state your problem, which is great.

Then you link the documentation, which I don't think is overly necessary, but otherwise you might just write it as

> The documentation (link) on Close states if I pass autoClose=true to Show then I don't need to call it; however, I wish to close it myself because...

Optionally here, you should include what happens if you pass `true`, does it work fine?You then mention it's a console application, which you should probably just put in your first sentence:

> I have the following class in a .net framework console, which manages a `SplashScreen`

The part about how you've debugged is great, although there's a typo on "definitely".

Two other minor notes: I think you're over using the lines, but it's not an issue, and you could omit c# from the title.

Ultimately this would leave you with the following question, which is much shorter:

---

I have the following class in a .net framework console, which manages a `SplashScreen`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace NamespaceName
{
    public class StackOverFlowCode
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassSplashScreen screen = new ClassSplashScreen();
            screen.ShowSplashScreen();
            screen.CloseSplashScreen();
        }

    }
    public class ClassSplashScreen
    {
        public SplashScreen splashscreen { get; set; }
        public ClassSplashScreen()
        {
            splashscreen = new SplashScreen("Resource Image Link");
        }
        public void ChangeSplashResource(SplashScreen resource)
        {
            splashscreen = resource;
        }
        public void ShowSplashScreen(bool autoClose = false)
        {
            splashscreen.Show(autoClose, true);
        }
        public void CloseSplashScreen()
        {
            splashscreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

The splash screen shows, but doesn't close. Note that I'm passing `autoClose` as `false` because I wish to close it myself. The [documentation for `Close`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.close?view=netframework-4.8) states that this is fine

It's definitely a problem with my class, because if I modify the `SplashScreen` directly it works fine:

```
ClassSplashScreen rss = new ClassSplashScreen();
rss.splashscreen.Show(false);
rss.splashscreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

I've ran the debugger through it but everything appears to be fine. How can I have my `SplashScreen` close when I call `Close` from `CloseSplashScreen`?

Comment: " I'd love to be able to suggest an edit for your approval but that is not possible" that's totally possible. You just need to edit it and OP can improve the post upon it. Editing is a form of communication.

Answer (score 8):

The tags seem to be noisy:
Only use tags that make a difference to your question.

I'd say these tags are not relevant for your question:

- [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods): your question is not about how to use methods, you are having questions about a specific method.
- [console-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console-application): it doesn't matter to you how you run the program, you have questions about the content of the application.
- [instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance): your question only mentions this as a sidenote, not as an essential part of your question.

Comment: A lot of those tags sound like burnination candidates.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think anything should be improved at all.

Your question explains what you did and your struggle. Code formatting is fine as well, it's concise and direct to the point.

Furthermore, you got an answer already and if something were bad formatted the guy who answered you would probably submit a edit (or not answer at all).

Not every question gets loads of upvotes but that's fine, if you keep asking helpful questions and contribute to others questions, the upvotes will increase!

Comment: and remember, up-votes are not the goal, sure they're an added side benefit but the goal is to provide quality Q&As.

Answer (score 5):

I have some suggestions for you.

First of all, don't highlight many many words with this formatting (backticks): ` `. Only use them for class names, variables when referred to within the question (like: This is my `Support.java` file. Or like this: I think the `x` variable might be causing the error.). You have used it just for highlighting the text. You can also use this formatting for method names like `print()`.

Next, logcats can be typed in quotes, but this line of code should not be typed there. It should look something like this:

> [System.Security.SecurityCritical]

The log highlights this line:

```
public void Close (TimeSpan fadeoutDuration);
```

Then don't use many `hr` tags or horizontal rule. You can use it, but don't clutter up things. Else everything is fine other than the unusual text formatting.

Comment: Not evident in the current version of the post, but you're absolutely right. That code formatting was waaaay overused. Code formatting is not for every proper noun you find. Don't know why this is so popular to do! _"What I have tried: `Debugging`"_  Just no just why

Answer (score 2):

Do not put tags in the title. It creates noise. There is dedicated space for tags.

Consider the 2 improvements @grolschie and @PatrickArtner have made. They made the title describe your problem. When you look at the title it has to stand out what the question is about, not what technologies you used.

[image]

People very often just brief through the text trying to make out what you are saying without spending much time on it. If you would like to catch their attention the title needs to be descriptive and clear. You shouldn't put tags, long error messages or make typos in it, because it decreases your chances of people taking you seriously.