# Is the hot meta posts curated/censored by removing unwanted questions?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, community-bulletin

So I wondered.

There's a pretty lively discussion going on in [New home page makes it seem like SO doesn't allow free use any more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386505/new-home-page-makes-it-seem-like-so-doesnt-allow-free-use-any-more) and  the question [Faster access to questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386495/faster-access-to-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1) was for a short time in the hot meta topics queue, one minute or so, before the hot meta queue reverted to

[image: hot meta queue]

[Developer Story tab tooltip behind top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386459/developer-story-tab-tooltip-behind-top-bar?cb=1) is last comment yesterday, not exactly hot

[We don't need this in our tag [inventory]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386489/we-dont-need-this-in-our-tag-inventory?cb=1) last comment 36 mins ago, last one before that 4 hours ago

[How could I have improved my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386473/how-could-i-have-improved-my-question?cb=1) last comment 2 hours ago.

Now if we lay it next to the questions at the top of this question, it seems like they are purposefully held out of the hot meta. [Faster access to questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386495/faster-access-to-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1) was for a short time in it before vanishing. That whilst on those two questions at the top of my question there is a lot of activity, votewise and comment wise.

Is the hot meta topic queue curated and censored to keep these "unwelcome for stackoverflow" discussions out of public view?

Comment: I don't think it is, posts frequently disappear and reappear in that list.

Comment: @Stijn I hope not, but with the question vanishing so quickly from hot meta posts, whilst normally questions stick around for a while for me, it makes me a tad paranoid.

Comment: according to this [answer by shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) the selection is random, changing every 20 min from all posts that fulfill the criteria. (Post score >= 3, Post age <= 3 days)

Comment: @Magisch ah, I remember there being a rework on the hot meta thing. It just seemed curious for me that for one minute that one post was on there, and then after a minute it was gone. That's a shorter time than the 20 minutes. Maybe they changed the algorithm? or curated the list that could be chosen from?

Comment: shouldiblamecaching.com. It could be that you looked a minute before the refresh. Anecdotally, I've seen the "New Homepage doesn't..." question in the hot meta posts: It's how I first saw it today.

Comment: @Magisch I was thinking the same thing, but The thing is, I was wondering why it wasn't in the list. There were 3 questions there, whilst I was typing my answer. Then I browsed a couple of others, saw the question pop up in hot meta, clicked on it habitually, then browsed a away, and then a minute later it was gone.